# Is it true wrap inside Elasticsearch bool:filter sets query in constant score mode, no matter what's wrapped inside?

Tags: elasticsearch

I tested it with many levels nesting, it seems a filter like the following:

```
{"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"bool": {"must": [{"bool": {"must": [{"bool": {"must": [{"term": {"stringField": "kimchy"}}]}}]}}]}}]}}}
```

runs in constant score mode, confirmed by `_search/explain=true` .

```
"_explanation":{"value":0.0,"description":"ConstantScore(stringField:kimchy)^0.0"
```

It seems to me as long as the top level is wrapped in a `bool:filter` or `constant-score`, the query runs without scoring. but i found no document in ES website claiming so, anyone know of a definitive answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's absolutely correct and that's mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context) in the official documentation:

> In a filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or No — **no scores are calculated**
> [...]
> Filter context is in effect whenever a query clause is passed to a filter parameter, such as **the filter or must_not parameters in the bool query**, the filter parameter in the constant_score query, or the filter aggregation.